# variable null, even without being called

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm attempting to use JavaScript to add rows to a table. I created an anonymous function `iterate` that iterates id names, and that works fine. The problem is somewhere in my class.

```
class CreateTable{
      constructor(text) {
    this.text = text
  }

  makeTableRow(){
    let self = this;
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      let el = document.createElement('td');
      el.setAttribute('id', iterate(i));
      row.appendChild(el);
    }
    let en = document.getElementById('id1');
    console.log(en);
    en.innerHTML = self.text;
    return row;
  }
}
```

I adapted this class from something that already works, with some tweaks. The `en` variable is returning a `typeError:en is null`, and I can't figure it out. What I want to do is create two empty `td` elements with callable ids, and then add text to the first element immediately. What is the actual problem that is going on here?

Comment: If `en` is `null`, it means there are no elements with an id of `'id1'`.

Comment: If you mean that you're trying to get one of the elements just created in the loop, you haven't actually inserted them into the DOM yet, so you can't find them with `.getElementById()`.

Comment: By the way, your snippet demonstrates a very poor use of a `class`. Just declare a stand-alone function instead.

Comment: @4castle That doesn't make sense though. `iterate` returns the string "id1" on the first iteration of the for loop

Comment: `document.getElementById` can only get elements which have been added to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.getElementById()` function returns `null` if there is no element with the specified ID *in the DOM*. The elements that you create in the loop have not been added to the DOM, they're appended to a `tr` that isn't in the DOM either (it's just returned from your function without having been appended to anything).

Just add the required text directly at the time you create the element:

```
makeTableRow(){
    let self = this;
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      let el = document.createElement('td');
      el.setAttribute('id', iterate(i));
      if (i === 0)                 // for first element
        el.innerHTML = self.text;  // set the content
      row.appendChild(el);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Incidentally, you say you want to create *two* td elements, but your loop only runs for *one* iteration. The `for` condition should be `i < 2` if you want it to run twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You helped in more ways than 1

Answer (score 0):

Is null because doesn't is identifying the "id", that meaning that you are writing your script before the id="id1".

You need to write your script at the end, just before of "body"

```
  .......
  <div id="id1">
  </div>
  .....
  <script>
  ....
  </script>
</body>
```